# Error when using SelectPDF on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, appharbor, selectpdf

When  using SelectPDF on Appharbor, I get the error `Conversion failure. Could not find 'Select.Html.dep'` Looking at the SelectPDF [docs](http://selectpdf.com/how-to-fix-conversion-failure-could-not-find-select-html-dep/), I see that the error means the `.dep` file was not copied to the project. I've removed it from my `.gitignore` and committed it to the repo but I still get the error. (I'm using the BitBucket -> Appharbor integration so that my code pushes and builds on AppHarbor every time I push to master.)

How can I get this file up into the `bin` folder on AppHarbor so SelectPDF will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using the steps outlined here: https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/924-deploy-unreferenced-files-to-bin-folder

Added an `AfterBuild` target to copy the missing `.dep` file.